# rownames and colnames with specific value

Tags: r, matrix, r-rownames

I have this matrix and i want to  get a 2 column matrix, where one column has the rowname and the other column, the colname of cells with value 1

```
x
     
   X1 X2 X3
X1  1 0   1
X2  0 1   0
X3  0 1   1
X4  1 0   0



str(x)
num [1:886, 1:886] 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

I want a matrix like this

```
# X1  X1 
# X1  X3   
# X2  X2   
# X3  X2   
# X3  X3   
# X4  X1
```

which are the pairs that have value=1

Comment: Could you add an example of what result you want to get ? Moreover, `x` here is not a vector but a matrix ?

Comment: Sorry! x is a matrix (i edited my question)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please also show what have you tried till now. SO is not a place to get your code written for free. Also telling what have you tried till now also shows that you are really looking to learn from the solution and are not just after solution

Answer (score 3):

here another option :

```
mm <- expand.grid(rownames(mat),colnames(mat))[as.vector(mat==1),]

 Var1 Var2
1    X1   X1
4    X4   X1
6    X2   X2
7    X3   X2
9    X1   X3
11   X3   X3
```

And to get the OP display , we order by the first column:

```
 mm[order(mm$Var1),]
   Var1 Var2
1    X1   X1
9    X1   X3
6    X2   X2
7    X3   X2
11   X3   X3
4    X4   X1
```

Here I mat is your imput , that I reproduce :

```
mat <- data.frame(X1=c(1,0,0,1),X2=c(0,1,1,0),X3=c(1,0,1,0))
rownames(mat)= paste0('X',1:4)

   X1 X2 X3
X1  1  0  1
X2  0  1  0
X3  0  1  1
X4  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it solved my problem! Can someone tell me how I name the new column names? I would like to rename Var1 and Var2

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
mat <- which(x==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
mat[,"col"] <- names(x)[mat[,"col"]]
mat[,"row"] <- rownames(mat)
```

Which will give :

```
   row  col 
X1 "X1" "X1"
X4 "X4" "X1"
X2 "X2" "X2"
X3 "X3" "X2"
X1 "X1" "X3"
X3 "X3" "X3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one line answer

```
x
##    X1 X2 X3
## X1  1  0  1
## X2  0  1  0
## X3  0  1  1
## X4  1  0  0


cbind(rownames(x)[row(x) * x], colnames(x)[col(x) * x])
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] "X1" "X1"
## [2,] "X4" "X1"
## [3,] "X2" "X2"
## [4,] "X3" "X2"
## [5,] "X1" "X3"
## [6,] "X3" "X3"
```